# getText is not accessible

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview

Passing an `editText` to the method `checkMQTTResources` as a `view`, and i make a `switch-case` on the id of each view passed to this method `checkMQTTResources`.

As shown below, trying to access the `getText` method of each view, but it is not allowed or not shown when i use the auto-complete feature.

Why i can not use 'getText'?

**Code**:

```
    btnStubView_Connect.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            checkMQTTResources(etStubView_ip);
        }
    });
}
protected void checkMQTTResources(View view) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(view.getId()) {

    case R.id.etSubView_ip:
        view.gettext //gettext is not allowed here, why?
        break;
    case R.id.etSubView_port:
        break;
    case R.id.etSubView_clientID:
        break;
    case R.id.etSubView_KATimer:
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why i can not use 'getText'

Because the method accepts a `View`, and while an `EditText` is a `View`, you will be able to access the public methods of the more generic class, the `View` class, which does not have such a method `getText()`.

To solve this, you should cast (convert) the view to the EditText, like:

```
((EditText)view).getText().toString();
```

or accept an `EditText` as a parameter instead of `View`:

```
protected void checkMQTTResources(EditText editText) {
   //...
   editText.getText().toString();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You missed to `typecast` `view` to `EditText`:

```
((EditText)view).getText();
```

Answer (score 1):

Two ways to solve your problem.

1. First cast your `View` into `EditText` then call `getText()`
2. Receive `EditText` itself

Answer (score 1):

`View` is top level  class in view hierarchy

```
java.lang.Object
   ↳    android.view.View
       ↳    android.widget.TextView
           ↳    android.widget.EditText
```

View didnt have `getText()` method basically it is define in `android.widget.TextView`. to call the `getText()` method downcasting is required